# Pandas/NumPy -- Plotting Dates as X axis

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

My Goal is just to plot this simple data, as a graph, with x data being dates ( date showing in x-axis) and price as the y-axis. Understanding that the dtype of the NumPy record array for the field date is datetime64[D] which means it is a 64-bit np.datetime64 in 'day' units. While this format is more portable, Matplotlib cannot plot this format natively yet. We can plot this data by changing the dates to DateTime.date instances instead, which can be achieved by converting to an object array: which I did below view the astype('0'). But I am still getting

**this error :**

```
 view limit minimum -36838.00750000001 is less than 1 and is an invalid Matplotlib date value. This often happens if you pass a non-DateTime value to an axis that has DateTime units
```

code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = pd.read_csv(r'avocado.csv')

df2 = df[['Date','AveragePrice','region']]
df2 = (df2.loc[df2['region'] == 'Albany'])

df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'])
df2['Date'] = df2.Date.astype('O')

plt.style.use('ggplot')
ax = df2[['Date','AveragePrice']].plot(kind='line', title ="Price Change",figsize=(15,10),legend=True, fontsize=12)
ax.set_xlabel("Period",fontsize=12)
ax.set_ylabel("Price",fontsize=12)

plt.show()
```

df.head(3)

```
    Unnamed: 0  Date    AveragePrice    Total Volume    4046    4225    4770    Total Bags  Small Bags  Large Bags  XLarge Bags type    year    region
0   0   2015-12-27  1.33    64236.62    1036.74 54454.85    48.16   8696.87 8603.62 93.25   0.0 conventional    2015    Albany
1   1   2015-12-20  1.35    54876.98    674.28  44638.81    58.33   9505.56 9408.07 97.49   0.0 conventional    2015    Albany
2   2   2015-12-13  0.93    118220.22   794.70  109149.67   130.50  8145.35 8042.21 103.14  0.0 conventional    2015    Albany
```

Comment: reason doing this `df2['Date'] = df2.Date.astype('O')` ?

Comment: you may have wrong date in your data set

Comment: what do you mean wrong date? Regarding you first question, to create an object. I am following this tutorial-->https://matplotlib.org/gallery/recipes/common_date_problems.html and it seemed to point me that way

Comment: remove those 2 zeroes from link

Comment: can you show me df2.head() ?

Comment: Unnamed: 0 Date AveragePrice Total Volume 4046 4225 4770 Total Bags Small Bags Large Bags XLarge Bags type year region
0 0 2015-12-27 1.33 64236.62 1036.74 54454.85 48.16 8696.87 8603.62 93.25 0.0 conventional 2015 Albany
1 1 2015-12-20 1.35 54876.98 674.28 44638.81 58.33 9505.56 9408.07 97.49 0.0 conventional 2015 Albany
2 2 2015-12-13 0.93 118220.22 794.70 109149.67 130.50 8145.35 8042.21 103.14 0.0 conventional 2015 Albany

Comment: post that in your question

Comment: can you remove this line `df2['Date'] = df2.Date.astype('O')` and try to run? then tell me the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df2 = df[['Date', 'AveragePrice', 'region']]
df2 = (df2.loc[df2['region'] == 'Albany'])
df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'])
df2 = df2[['Date', 'AveragePrice']]
df2 = df2.sort_values(['Date'])
df2 = df2.set_index('Date')

print(df2)

ax = df2.plot(kind='line', title="Price Change")
ax.set_xlabel("Period", fontsize=12)
ax.set_ylabel("Price", fontsize=12)

plt.show()
```

**output:**

[image]